# simple cipher not working bc of indexing?

Tags: python, encryption, indexing, typeerror

I'm trying to write a simple cipher, using a dictionary for both alphabets, and I keep getting an error "TypeError: string indices must be integers".  How do I index the value of c??

```
cipher_alphabet = dict(zip('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
'phqgiumeaylnofdxjkrcvstzwb'))

def cipher(text, cipher_alphabet, option='encipher'):
    result = ""
    for c in text:
        if c in cipher_alphabet:
            result = result + cipher_alphabet[c]
        else:
            result = result + c
    print(ciphertext)
```

Comment: Other than `ciphertext` being not defined not sure what issue is. e.g. `print(result)` prints the encrypted text.

Comment: Can you show how you call the function? The error might be there

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the print command, but it's still the same error.  I'm calling it like this:
    cipher('defend the east wall of the castle', 'd')

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, as soon as I replace "ciphertext" with "result":

```
>>> cipher_alphabet = dict(zip('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
'phqgiumeaylnofdxjkrcvstzwb'))

>>> def cipher(text, cipher_alphabet, option='encipher'):
    result = ""
    for c in text:
        if c in cipher_alphabet:
            result = result + cipher_alphabet[c]
        else:
            result = result + c
    print result


>>> cipher("bloo",cipher_alphabet)
hndd
```

Comment: aha!  I've been calling it wrong.  I wasn't calling the dict!  Thanks so much for that.

Answer (score 0):

So fixing `ciphertext` to `result` makes it work but there are other ways of doing this, e.g. using `dict.get()` with a default value:

```
def cipher(text, cipher_alphabet, option='encipher'):
    return ''.join(cipher_alphabet.get(c, c) for c in text)

>>> cipher('hello world', cipher_alphabet)
einnd tdkng
```

Using `str.maketrans`:

```
cipher_alphabet = str.maketrans('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'phqgiumeaylnofdxjkrcvstzwb')

def cipher(text, cipher_alphabet, option='encipher'):
    return text.translate(cipher_alphabet)

>>> cipher('hello world', cipher_alphabet)
einnd tdkng
```